# Buscar nomes de todos os ficheiros de uma pasta?

Tags: php, jquery

Eu tenho um código feito para buscar imagens mas é um pouco mais complicado que isso.

```
$("#publi_not").change(function(){
    var p = 0;
    var r = 1;
    var val = $(this).val();
    var valor = $('#publi_not option[value="'+val+'"]').html();
    var n_pub = $('#publi_not option[value="'+val+'"]').data("numero")+1;
    var balance = $("#imagens_not").get(0).files.length;
    var pub_txt = $("#text_img").val();
    var pub = pub_txt;
    for(t=1;t<=balance;t++){
        if(n_pub<=t){
            r=1;
        }
        $(".images"+p+" .images_pub").html("<img src='pubs/"+valor+"/"+valor+r+".png' style='width:100%' /><div class='altera' style='margin-top:-20px;top:0;left:2px;position:absolute;color:white;'><small><small><small><b>"+pub+"</b></small></small></small></div>");
        p++;
        r++;
    }
});
```

O código é executado quando eu mudo o valor num `select` que depois irá adicionar uma div abaixo consoante o que for selecionado.

O problema é o seguinte. Recentemente criei uma tabela (Pois o anterior era baseado em testes) que tem os nomes das imagens mas como é que eu faço para mostrar os ficheiros?

Eu pensei em apenas ler os ficheiros de uma pasta com o nome da publicidade mas nem isso eu consegui.

Comment: Como é o caminho das tuas imagens? `pubs/um_valor/um_valor_0.png`, `pubs/um_valor/um_valor_1.png`, etc?

Comment: Isso é como está agora, mas o caminho é `pubs/NOME_PRINCIPAL/NOME_DA_IMAGEM` porque dantes as imagens era todas numeradas porque eram de teste

Comment: Então os nomes das imagens não são previsíveis? O Javascript não vai conseguir ler os ficheiros que estão na pasta porque corre do lado do cliente, no browser. Consegues mostrar alguns caminhos reais para imagens? Para perceber se há alguma lógica no javascript que seja possível usar